# self guided electronics text recommendations

Tags: books

Can anyone recommend a good text or texts that they have experience with for someone learning electronics on their own. I have taken some very basic college courses, but I want to know more. There are so many books out there that claim to be geared toward this, but I'd love to hear from some of the more experienced people with higher knowledge levels about what they would personally recommend. I have done a lot of searching and was going to base my selection on online user reviews, but I thought some input from people on here would be valuable. I have a lot of experience with DC electrical systems, and some with AC electrical systems, but only a small bit with electronics.

As I work through some self learning and project using online resources, I am quickly deciding that I need some actual text reference material.

I apologize if this is an inappropriate place for this question.

Thank you for any info!

Comment: @Martin My apologies, I just went under the "books" tag and didn't see that question / thread. I will delete.

Comment: Radio-Electronics magazine was superb technician-level presentation of circuits, ideal for my high-school learning. They would *explain* how the circuits world, empirically; time constants and frequency responses and gains were discussed.